# Can I use different file types in srcset?

Tags: html, webp, lighthouse, srcset

I'm trying to combine .jpg and .webp, but it doesn't work for me..

`<img src="flower.jpg" srcset="flower.webp 480w, flower.jpg 1080w" sizes="50vw">`

Answer (score 2):

The only requirement for the image URL in a `srcset` attribute is that the URL is valid and points to an image. The image types do not have to be the same. See the [WHATWG standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#srcset-attribute) or the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset) for more information.

However, if you are including multiple image types for performance reasons (serving better-compressed images while providing fallbacks for older browsers), the [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) tag would be the way to go.

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="flower.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="flower.jpg" alt="[something that describes the image]">
</picture>
```

You can also provide different image widths with the `srcset` and `sizes` attributes on the [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) tag.